# How do I connect a public-facing load balancer to EC2 instances in a private VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-vpc

## Background

I want to deploy a laravel application to Elastic Beanstalk. The setup includes a VPC with two private and two public subnets. The EC2, RDS etc. are all in the private subnets.

Only the ELB is in the public ones. And should route everything into the private ones.

### Issue

If I try to connect over the ELB I receive a TIMEOUT error.

I am not sure if this is a configuration problem (VPC/Subnets) or an application (EB) error.

The requests however seem to go through and get routed correctly, I guess. Because if I check the Elastic Beanstalk logs for example the `httpd/access.log`

I see the requests made through the ELB.

`13:38:20
10.0.2.52 (94.79.175.190) - - [22/Oct/2018:13:38:19 +0000] "GET /loadbalancertest HTTP/1.1" 307 307 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.`

The healthcheck however seem to work fine. And the application state is OK.

### Infrastructure

- 1 VPC
- 2 Private Subnets
- 2 Public Subnets

---

#### ELB

The ELB is in the two public subnets.

**ELB Security Group Settings**

Inbound: HTTP / TCP / 80 / 0.0.0.0/0

Outbound: HTTP / TCP / 80 / 0.0.0.0/0

---

#### EC2 Instance (created by EB)

**VPC Security Group Settings**

Inbound: HTTP / TCP / 80 / sg-03xxxxx (ELB SG)

Outbound: All traffic / 0.0.0.0/0

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your ELB is configured correctly.

You have a problem with your backend configuration. The HTTP service is returning HTTP status 307 which is a temporary redirect for your health check (unless I am reading your log file wrong - you can never be sure what is what with custom log formats). What is odd is that you have `307 307` in your log file. The first 307 is the HTTP status and the second is the number of bytes returned for the request.

Connect to one of your backend instances and then use `curl` to another backend instance and verify that the health check url is working correctly. Then verify that the default home page is also working correctly.